# ERROR Node JS - Node-SASS- Visual C++ Runtime Library Error on windows 7

Tags: c++, node.js, node-sass

When i start gulp, i get Windows ALERT with error.

[image]

- NPM version> 2.14.9
- NODE version> 0.12.8
- NODE SASS version> 2.14.9

I use Windows 7

[image]

Thank you very much. Im desperate.